# sympy - finding analytical form of infinite geometric series with symbolic growth rates

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I tried to find the analytical form of the infinite geometric series using sympy:

```
from sympy import *
i, T, r = symbols('i T r')
Sum((1/(1+r))**i,(i,T,oo)).doit()
simplify(Sum((1/(1+r))**i,(i,T,oo)))
simplify(Sum((1/(1+r))**i,(i,1,oo)).doit())
_.n()
```

The closed form is a routine exercise of algebra, so I assumed it won't be challenging for sympy. But the result is always the non-derived summation form.
The finite sum, however, can be evaluated to obtain closed form:

```
simplify(Sum((1/(1+r))**i,(i,1,T)).doit())
```

Is this problem solvable with sympy? If no, can it be solved by any other package of Python?

Answer (score 1):

Is `r` positive? If so, declare it so and you will get a closed form:

```
>>> r = Symbol('r', positive=True)
>>> i, T = symbols('i T')
>>> Sum((1/(1+r))**i,(i,T,oo)).doit().simplify()
       1 - T
(r + 1)     
------------
     r
```